# Converting String to Enum give Error in java?

Tags: java, string, enums

All The Examples of `String to Enum` Convertion taking only one String But In my Example String like this...

```
String allDays="MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY";
```

and My Enum Class like this..

```
public enum WeekdayType {

    MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), WEDNESDAY(
            Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY), FRIDAY(
            Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(
            Calendar.SUNDAY);

    private int day;

    private WeekdayType(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
}
```

So in that Time `WeedayType.valueOf(allDay)` is giving error.....
Any suggestions for this..

Comment: Are you getting  _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.java.core.Test$WeekdayType.MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY_ error. If yes this is the correct behavior. What output your are expecting?

Comment: correct IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Your String is _String allDays = "MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY";_ and _WeedayType.valueOf(allDay)_ will give you the _IllegalArgumentException_ only. The valid values you can pass to valueOf method are "MONDAY", "TUESDAY" etc.(i.e your enum names)

Comment: So in that case i can split my String passing the valueOf() .. is it correct Process..?

Comment: If your input string _"allDays"_ is fixed yes you can do Split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be getting the below error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.java.core.Test$WeekdayType.MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY`

The reason is you are passing the following String to your *WeedayType* enum, which is an illegal argument as the exception says.

```
String allDays = "MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY"; 
WeedayType.valueOf(allDay);
```

The valid values you can pass to valueOf method are "MONDAY", "TUESDAY" etc.(i.e your enum names). Other values gives you java.lang.IllegalArgumentException which is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
String allDays = "MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY";
        for (String day : allDays.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(WeekdayType.valueOf(day));
        }
```